# Windows Phone Mutex issue

Tags: windows-phone-7, mutex

I made some researches about mutexes, but could not find anything to worth to clarify what I want as much as I can understand. I can use mutexes on linux easily. But I don't know why my mutexes won't work on my application. I also looked for some examples, and implemented it. But no way;

Here is my mutex initilaziation;

```
public static Mutex mutex = new Mutex(true,"mut");
```

Here I used my mutex to lock;

```
private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) //Challenge Start/Stop
        {

            StartLocationService(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
            mutex.WaitOne();
            mutex.WaitOne();

                MessageBox.Show("I'm in mutex");
///...
        }
```

I did this just to see if mutex is cared by my application. But no ways, my application shows "IM in mutex" message without getting any release signal from somewhere. Normally, there must be a deadlock, but no.

What I'm trying to do is, before StartLocationService fully completed, I don't want the message to appear. I also tried mutex.ReleaseMutex(); within end of StartLocationService function. But it did not work too.

I wish semaphores had existed in WP.

Please help me; Thanks

Comment: A mutex is re-entrant on the same thread.  Don't use a mutex on the UI thread.

Comment: Named mutexes are only useful for communicating across processes. When synchronizing threads within the same process, use monitor (e.g. using lock C# keyword) instead, not only they are easier to use but they are also faster.

Answer (score 2):

You have no deadlock because you passed 'true' for the first parameter of the Mutex, which means that the mutex is initially owned by the thread who created it. That is, your main thread.

For your example, what you must do is set the constructor's parameter to False, then call `mutex.WaitOne()`. This should effectively block your main thread. Then, call `mutex.ReleaseMutex()` at the end of the `StartLocationService` method.

Now that's for the theory. I wouldn't recommend you to do that, because the main thread is the UI thread. It means that the UI will become unresponsive until the location service has finished initializing, which is awful UX. You should rather display some kind of loading screen, and hide it at the end of the `StartLocationService` method.

Note that you can use a [ManualResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.threading.manualresetevent%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) instead of a mutex. The end result will be the same, but it might be a tad more intuitive to use.

Comment: Hi; Unfortunately it's not working when I changed it into false. Did you notice that it is a button function? This may happen because of this? To be precise; When the button pressed, it initializes StartLocationService function, and I want it to wait to finish this task and show message. It is as simply as I told. What should I do?